# Nuxtjs v3 and Tailwindcss v3 PostCSS@8 not compatible

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss

i'm trying to install Tailwindcss in my nuxt project

I use fresh install from nuxt https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation

```
npx nuxi init nuxt3-app
```

and follow tailwindcss installation

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs

But when i start the app `npm run dev` i got this error

```
ERROR  Cannot restart nuxt:  postcss@8 is not compatible with current version of nuxt (0.0.0). Expected: >=2.15.3
```

I don't know how to fix it, and cannot find any answer online, i appreciate any help, thankyou

Comment: You can use Windi CSS (nearly exactly the same thing, but personally slightly better and faster). Windi CSS uses the same syntax as Tailwind CSS and works with Nuxt 3. You can find documentation on how to install it here : [https://windicss.org/].

Answer (score 53, accepted):

At this time, this documentation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs only working for nuxtjs v2, but it still possible using v3 if you follow this guide :

Don't use `@nuxt/postcss8` currently it's only work for nuxtjs v2

1. Install tailwindcss, postcss and autoprefixer

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init
```

2. Update your `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './assets/**/*.{vue,js,css}',
    './components/**/*.{vue,js}',
    './layouts/**/*.vue',
    './pages/**/*.vue',
    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  ],
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

3. Update your `postcss.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

4. Create `assets/css/tailwind.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

5. Update your `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css'],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: require('./postcss.config.js'),
    },
  }
})
```

6. Import your css in `app.vue`. (optional) in previous version they recommend us to import tailwindcss in app.vue instead of nuxt.config

```html
<script setup>
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css'
</script>
```

Comment: just tested not working :s

Comment: I test that it's work!, thanks ~

Comment: why do you add `nuxt.config` to your tailwind configs `content` ?

Comment: @vhflat i just use configuration guide from [official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs), feel free to use your own configuration

Comment: The latest version of nuxt does not like it when you `require` inside of `nuxt.config.ts`, so I just added the configuration of `postcss.config.js` (the object that is being exported) directly into the `postcssOptions` object within `nuxt.config.ts`
Works like a charm!

Comment: Hey I got tailwind working, but it does not seem to update on file-save. I have to rebuild the server after making a change for the tailwind css to take effect... Does this work with you?

Comment: This is not the recommended way of setting up a nuxt3 project. See https://nuxt.com/modules/tailwindcss and https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/bundling/

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem too, as Nuxt 3 requires a different way to integrate Tailwind. The following is to install Tailwind as a Nuxt module, rather than independently. This is easier, as it requires a lot less configuration (no need to edit *postcss.config.js*, a bit less config required for *nuxt.config.js*).

[Version 5.0 of the Nuxt Tailwind module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/releases/tag/v5.0.0-0) brings in support for Nuxt 3. Full default installation is as follows:

### Step 1

To install, we can dev install this (yarn add or npm install) with *@nuxtjs/tailwindcss@latest* or whichever version (after 5.1) you need.

```
 yarn add -D @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@latest
```

### Step 2

Then in **nuxt.config.js**, add the module to the modules array:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
    ]
})
```

### Step 3

Create a **tailwind.config.js** file either manually or by using the terminal command:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

### Step 4

Add the Tailwind directives to your main CSS file (./assets/css/tailwind.css by default, or [configurable in your *nuxt.config.js* file](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/options)).

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

### Step 5

After this, try running your dev or build commands, and it should be working correctly.

Comment: Tested with Nuxt v3.0.0-rc.8 and works well. Thanks!

Comment: same here, works!

Comment: Works great with me

Answer (score 3):

By using `npx nuxi init nuxt3-app`, you're creating a Nuxt v3 app. Nuxt 3 is still very much in public beta, so it's likely you'll come across issues which the team would no doubt love to take a look at for you- if you raise it as an issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues).

If it suits your needs, Nuxt v2 is available as a stable alternative. Follow the [guide that you referenced](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs) to setup a new app, and you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    "./components/**/*.{vue,js}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
    "./app.vue",
  ],
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: This is a great start to an answer; please describe how your code fixes the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, run this command to install ***tailwind css***:

```
npm i -D @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@latest
```

---

Second, in your ***nuxt.config.ts***, copy/paste the following:

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss']
})
```

---

Third, in the root directory create **assets/css/main.css** file, then
copy/paste the following codes in the **main.css** file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

---

Finally, test if it works in your **App.vue** file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

Extra: if you want the tailwind ***intellisense***, run the command:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

then in **tailwind.config.js**:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

It should be working like a charm!

Comment: Thx, saved me a lot of time as all the nuxt 3 guides for tailwind are outdated!

Comment: 2023 and still works :))

Answer (score 1):

At the time I'm writing this, the accepted answer doesn't work for me; it may be that since December things may have changed (there's Nuxt 3 RC2 at the moment, stable version is expected in a few months).

Nonetheless, there's a [dedicated plugin](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/) *that works just fine* for Nuxt and **that supports Nuxt3 out of the box**. Just follow [these instructions](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup) to make it happen. There's plenty of documentation for anyone to follow.

**Important.** I don't know why, but such instructions lack an important step, which may be so trivial they take it for granted. Just remember to add the following three lines into your `main.css` (or `tailwind.css`) file, wherever that is:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated my `nuxt.config.ts` with the codes below and this works fine in my project. This is literally a combination of solutions explained above. :).

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
    ],
    css: ["@/assets/css/tailwind.css"],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

configure your `nuxt.config.ts` file with this.

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["@/assets/css/main.css"],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs#3) updated guide and it works with nuxt 3

Answer (score 0):

If you followed tailwind official docs to [integrate with Nuxt3](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs#3), maybe the issue is just because of not adding the root's `app.vue` file into `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app.vue',
    // ...rest of the list 
  ],
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```